# Existing ASP .Net Webform App - how to add a dedicated client login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on, multi-tenant

Asp .Net WebForm App
Using MembershipProvider for authenitcation against an SQL Server Database.

Application currenlty serves multiple clients with one login page.

A new client wants to setup SSO (ServiceProviderInitated) to their IDP Server.

Currently my web.config redirects everyone to the main login.aspx

I need the easiest solution for quick turnaround, but will keep enterprise solutions for future growth in my back pocket.

So for all 100 existing clients, I want them to continue to use serviceprovider.com/login.aspx

But for client 101, I want them to hit a serviceprovider.com/login101.aspx
Within that login101.aspx I was going to setup SSO using SAML.

Basically I want a hidden page; i'll give client101 the link to publish to their users.

Any help is greatly appreciated -

Thx,

Boyd

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for creating a proof of concept. Your question is not specific enough.

Comment: Sorry - Let me know what I can expand on -